# Шорткод в WordPress

Tags: php, html, wordpress, шорткод, shortcode

Есть кусок кода (html+php) который выводит посты из определенного типа постов в виде карусели, мне нужно чтобы этот блок можно было выводить в определенном месте, указанном в админке. Пробовал создать шорткод, но никак не получается. Может кто подскажет как правильно создать шорткод чтобы выводились посты?

Вот собственно код:

```
<?php $otziv = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'otziv', 'posts_per_page' => 100 ) ); ?>
  <div class="jcarousel-wrapper">
  <div class="jcarousel">
  <ul><?php while ( $otziv->have_posts() ) : $otziv->the_post(); ?>
  <li> 
  <div class="otziv-img"><?php the_post_thumbnail(array( 300,300)); ?></div>
  <div class="otziv-name"><?php the_title(); ?></div>
  <div class="otziv-text"><?php the_content(); ?></div>
  </li><?php endwhile; ?>
  </ul>
  </div>
  <a href="#" class="jcarousel-control-prev"></a>
  <a href="#" class="jcarousel-control-next"></a>
  </p>
  </div>               
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Comment: шорткод должен же принимать какие-то входные параметры, или они не меняются? Например кол-во выводимых объектов

Comment: сейчас меня интересует только вопрос как вывести это с помощью шорткода?

Comment: А вам ответ так чтоб самому не думать или пример, чтоб подумать и разобраться?

Comment: второе..........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот пример рабочего шорткода, в который можно передать параметры:

```
add_shortcode( 'my-shortcode', 'my_custom_shortcode' );

function my_custom_shortcode() {
    ob_start();
    $query = new WP_Query( array(
        'post_type' => 'otziv',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
    ) );
    if ( $query->have_posts() ) { ?>

        <div class="jcarousel-wrapper">

          <div class="jcarousel">

              <ul>

                <?php while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();

                    $output = '';
                    $output .= '<li>';
                    $output .= '<div class="otziv-img">' . the_post_thumbnail() . '</div>';
                    $output .= '<div class="otziv-name">' . the_title() . '</div>';
                    $output .= '<div class="otziv-text">' . the_excerpt() . '</div>';
                    $output .= '</li>';
                    echo $output; ?>

                <?php endwhile; ?>

              </ul>

          </div>

          <a href="#" class="jcarousel-control-prev"></a>
          <a href="#" class="jcarousel-control-next"></a>

        </div>

    <?php return ob_get_clean();;
    }
}

// Use shortcode [my-shortcode]
```

Вот и попробуйте разобраться, как это работает

[Вот кодекс WordPress с инфой, как создавать шорткоды](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API)

Comment: ну такие примеры я знаю, мне бы пример чисто для моего случая
насколько я понял, для моего, чтобы сделать шорткод для моего куска кода, его нужно кардинально изменить?

Comment: Уберите внутреннее содержимое и вставьте туда свой код (внутрь функции)

Comment: По сути нужно создать функцию и зарегистрировать шорткод

Comment: в том то и дело что не работает, читайте в вопросе, пробовал по разному

Comment: Не хотите думать, пробуйте готовое решение, исправил ответ